# Google TV remote volume up/down not registering

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, google-tv, hdmi-cec

Hey all I have been trying to get my remotes volume up/down buttons to register in my app but they never seem to do anything when I press them?

I have tried:

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int volume = (Integer)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
        Log.i("Tag", "Action : "+ intent.getAction() + " / volume : "+volume);
    }
}
```

and also

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;

        switch (keyCode) {
            case 20:
                return false;
            case 22:
                fastForward();
                return false;
            case 21:
                rewind();
                return false;
            case 23:
                if (mTransportControlGlue.isPlaying()) {
                    mTransportControlGlue.pause();
                } else {
                    mTransportControlGlue.play();
                }

                return false;
          
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But like I said, every time I hit the buttons they never fire any of those above. The only ones that register are the Dpad up/down/left/right, center button and the back button.

I cam change the volume just fine using this code:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int actualVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

But that does me no good if I cant detect the volume up/down being pressed...

The google TV remote looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know what I am missing?